# Traefik - Unable to expose redis docker containers with the same port for different domains

Tags: redis, docker-compose, port, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to set up a Redis with docker-compose for different environments.
Therefore I need to expose two domains with traefik on the same port:

- domain.com:6379
- domain-dev.com:6379

I can't expose those ports on the container, because they are running on the same server.

My docker-compose file (for domain-dev) looks like this:

```
version: '2' 
services:
redis:
  container_name: redis-signalr-dev
image: redis
volumes:
  - ./redis-signalr-data:/data
restart: always
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.backend=redis-signalr-dev
  - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain-dev.com
  - traefik.port=6379
  - traefik.docker.network=traefik_default
  - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=redis
networks:
  - traefik_default
volumes:
  redis-signalr-data:

networks: 
  traefik_default:
    external: true
```

I also tried to configure the treafik to use the following endpoint:

```
--entrypoints='Name:redis Address::6379'
```

When connecting to "domain-dev.com:6379" a connection cannot be astablished.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traefik is a reverse proxy for http, not a tcp load balancer. So traefik itself (usually) opens ports 80 and 443 for ingress and forwards incoming http requests to the given http-able backends. The port you specify in your compose service labels is the port of the container, the traffic should be passed to.

So if you run a nodejs (http) server on port 3000, you would connect to `http://yourdomain:80` and traefik would forward the requests to your nodejs container on port 3000. This means that by specifying a port on a compose service, you will not open this port on your host.

In your example running redis with its custom protocol, traefik is not a solution as traefik only does http proxying. To expose redis on your host (if you really want to do that), just use regular docker port mappings and point your domains to your docker hosts. Doing this, there is no way to use the same port with different domains, just specify two different ports for your both instances. For http this works by traefik inspecting the http requests and doing routing based on the host header.

Answer (score 1):

Traefik 2.0 will have TCP support: https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/4587

Until then you'd have to use NGINX or similar.